# How can all of the virial coefficients be found for a gas that obeys the van der Waals equation of state?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, physical-chemistry, gas

For a gas that obeys the van der Waals equation of state,

$ \left(p+\frac{an^2}{V^2}\right)(V-nb) = nRT $

what are *all* of the virial coefficients $B_1$, $B_2$,... in the Virial Expansion?

$ pV = nRT \left[1+B_1\frac{n}{V} + B_2 \left(\frac{n}{V}\right)^2 + \cdots \right] $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels a bit like a homework question, so you will only get half of the answer and need to do the final part. Make sure you understand what is going on though, so you can finish fast!

You need to try and write the VdW equation in the form suggested, and then find terms $\sim n/V$ or $\sim n^2 / V^2$ and identify the coefficients ($B_1$ and $B_2$ in this case).

You can start by rewriting

$$(p+{an^2 \over V^2})(V-nb) = nRT$$
as
$$pV-pnb+{an^2\over V}-{abn^3\over V^2} = nRT$$

so that

$$p(V-nb)=nRT+{an^2\over V}+{abn^3\over V^2}$$

Notice that we had to keep the $p$-dependet terms on the left, because pressure has to *only* appear on the left. On the other hand, $V$ can appear on the right but only in powers of $n/V$. So we need to decouple things.

To do that, we first collect all things on the right:

$$p(V-nb)=nRT\left(1+{a \over RT} {n\over V}+{ab\over RT}{n^2\over V^2}\right)$$

and you see we only get powers of $n/V$ inside the parenthesis.

We would be done if we did not have that annoying $p(V-nb)$ term that is keeping an extra $..-nb$ on the left.

To get rid of that, we can use the fact that

$$p(V-nb)=pV(1-b{n\over V})$$

and we can now isolate $pV$ and divide by the remaining term

$$pV = nRT {1\over 1-b{n\over V}}\left(1+{a \over RT} {n\over V}+{ab\over RT}{n^2\over V^2}\right)$$

And you see that we have $pV$ on the left (good) and only powers of $n/V$ on the right (good). Unfortunately, one $n/V$ is at the denominator still...

So all that is left - and I leave it to you so you can finish the exercise - is to expand ${1\over 1-b{n\over V}}$ in series (because we assume $nb\ll V$ of course, as it is a correction) and again collect terms in order $\sim n / V$, $\sim n^2 / V^2$, $\sim n^3 / V^3$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by JalfredP is of course correct, but the derivation can be made simpler and more explicit. Namely,
$$
p+\frac{an^2}{V^2} = \frac{nRT}{V-nb}
= \frac{nRT}{V}\frac{1}{1-b\frac{n}{V}}
= \frac{nRT}{V}\sum_{k\geq 0} \Bigl( b\frac{n}{V} \Bigr)^k.
$$
Therefore,
$$
pV = -\frac{an^2}{V} + nRT \sum_{k\geq 0} \Bigl( b\frac{n}{V} \Bigr)^k = nRT\biggl( 1 + \bigl(b-\frac{a}{RT})\frac{n}{V} + \sum_{k\geq 2} b^k \Bigl( \frac{n}{V} \Bigr)^k \biggr),
$$
from which we see that $B_1 = b-\frac{a}{RT}$ and, for $k\geq 2$, $B_k=b^k$.